# How can I find the Active Directory users who have the "Cannot Change Password" set by LDAP query?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I want to find out list of users whose account is set to "cannot change password". How can I find by LDAP query? Script is also appreciated. I just need to find out the list.

Comment: Copy-pasting the title into the question and hitting "post" is your level of effort?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This LDAP search filter should find what you have asked:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=64))
```

This works due to the [Bitwise operation Extensible Match Rules](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Filtering%20for%20Bit%20Fields) provided within Active Directory.